# Creating Objects in Javascript with Constructor

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying this code

```
var mark = new Employee;
mark.name = 'Doe, Mark';
mark.dept = 'admin';
mark.projects = ['navigator'];

console.log(mark);
```

But the console won't show anything when i try to print it. It shows only when i use new Object. What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have Employee already?

Comment: The problem with the code is that there _is_ no constructor.

Comment: No i don't. I just do testing to see if i can construct objects this way. That must be it though! I know its a noob question. I am just doing my baby-steps into details of the Objects

Comment: Wait for @Mark_M to decide to finish editing and adding rather than posting all at once and then refer to his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `Employee` as a constructor function:

```js
function Employee() {}
var mark = new Employee();
mark.name = 'Doe, Mark';
mark.dept = 'admin';
mark.projects = ['navigator'];

console.log(mark);
```

This will also allow you to set properties with the constructor like:

```js
function Employee(name){
    this.name = name
}
var mark = new Employee('Doe, Mark');
mark.dept = 'admin';
mark.projects = ['navigator'];

console.log(mark);
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. I have just tried 'this' and i think i start to get it.